# Which annotations are 'mapping annotations' as referenced by the JPA specification?

Tags: java, jpa

In [JPA 2.1 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf), Section 2.3.1 (page 27):

> The default
>   access type of an entity hierarchy is determined by the placement of mapping annotations on the
>   attributes of the entity classes and mapped superclasses of the entity hierarchy that do not explicitly
>   specify an access type.

In the above sentence, what is and what is not "mapping annotation"? Are all annotations in `javax.persistence` package mapping annotations? Does the specification provide the complete list of mapping annotations?

Comment: Not all things in computer science (and in engineering in general) are strictly defined. Which problem are you trying to solve, and we'll tell you whether an annotation is a mapping one or not.

Comment: What I want to do is to get an ability to determine which access type is used for an entity. To do that I am reading the JPA specification but the specification seems not to be clear enough. Hibernate 4.3 User Manual is much clearer because it says: "By default the access type of a class hierarchy is defined by the position of the `@Id` or `@EmbeddedId` annotations."

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the term *mapping annotation* is not explicitly defined in [JPA 2.1 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf). However, the first section of Chapter 11 is named *Annotations for Object/Relational Mapping* which suggests that you can find the list of *mapping annotations* in this section.

Comment: Thanks for the list. The list contains `@Id` which is beleived to be a mapping annotation because it is used in the Example 2.2.1, which shows an example of property access. But unfortunately the list contains also `@Transient` which seems not to be a mapping annotation.

Comment: @npcode Although `@Transient` does not directly map an object model piece of data onto a database model piece of data It can still be called a mapping annotation as it is used to create an Object/Relational Mapping logic. However, it is not a definition based statement but my personal opinion.

Comment: If `@Transient` is a mapping annotation, the specification has a contradiction because it says: "Mapping annotations must not be applied to fields or properties that are transient or Transient."

Comment: @npcode You are right it is confusing. This statement might mean that if a field is transient or it is annotated with a mapping annotation `@Transient` then it cannot be annotated with any other mapping annotation. As mentioned in the spec you should probably "See http://jpa-spec.java.net to comment on and discuss this specification".

Comment: Thanks a lot. I posted my question on the user mailing list. https://java.net/projects/jpa-spec/lists/users/archive/2015-10/message/0

Answer (score 0):

Not all annotations in the javax.persistence package are mapping annotations, and not all mapping annotations can be placed on a field/property of an entity.

The one you posted discusses mapping annotations that are placed on attributes (field/property) of entity classes.

The spec has a list of these annotations. You can also view it [here](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/annotations).